# Query PIVOT ou SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

A minha consulta é a seguinte:

```
 mysql> select product_id, presentation, price from Variant where product_id = "1604";
  +------------+-------------------------+-------+
  | product_id | presentation            | price |
  +------------+-------------------------+-------+
  |       1604 | Unitário = R$ 11,90     |  11.9 |
  |       1604 | 5 Peças = R$ 5,00 cada  |    25 |
  |       1604 | Bluesky Todas           |    15 |
  +------------+-------------------------+-------+
   3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Como eu faria para separar esses 3 resultados para o mesmo ID 1604 em colunas distintas no SQL?

Exemplo: `presentation1, presentation2, presentation3` separado em colunas

Answer (score 1):

### Simular o Pivot dinamicamente

O MySQL não possuí funcionalidade de `Pivot`. Nesse caso você tem duas opções.

- Gerar uma coluna para cada caso em um `SUM` com `CASE`.
- Gerar dinamicamente esse mesmo SQL se o conteúdo da coluna for dinâmico.

No caso estático, seria algo como:

```
select product_id,
  sum(case when presentation = 'Unitário = R$ 11,90 ' THEN price END) presentation1,
  sum(case when presentation = '5 Peças = R$ 5,00 cada' THEN price END) presentation2,
  sum(case when presentation = 'Bluesky Todas' THEN price END) presentation3
from product
where product_id = 1604
```

No caso dinâmico, ficaria algo como:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @rowid = 0;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
    'sum(case when presentation = ''',
      presentation,
      ''' then price end) AS ',
      'presentation',
      @rowid := @rowid + 1 
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM 
(SELECT presentation 
 FROM product
 GROUP BY presentation
) AS p;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'SELECT product_id, ', 
  @sql, 
  ' from product where product_id = 1604'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Adicionei a query dinâmica nesse [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t16WsM1M8P65RzdpXFnij1/4) para ver funcionando com mais registros.

Comment: na forma dinamica me retornou um erro:   
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ''009- Zener 0,5W from product where product_id = 1604' na linha 1

Comment: No caso estático como ficaria sem colocar os nomes  'Unitário = R$ 11,90 '  ?

Comment: Tente rodar o exemplo do [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t16WsM1M8P65RzdpXFnij1/4). Se você mudou os dados ou tem algum caractere diferente na sua tabela pode estar influenciando na execução.

Comment: Sobre não colocar os nomes, apenas se você tiver uma tabela cujos nomes tem um código associado. Nesse caso você pode fazer um JOIN e usar o código relacionado a descrição ao invés da descrição.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo ?